# Inserts from Azure Webapp to Azure PostgreSQL Database sometimes dropping out?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, azure, docker, psycopg2

I have a webapp (Python, Docker container) on Azure that does multiple inserts into multiple tables for an Azure PostgreSQL database I set up within the same service plan. The database has plenty of storage and vCores, and allows for 250 connections.

When I look at the data directly within the database, sometimes I'll notice that the timestamps are behind and nothing is being inserted into the database, to which I restart the web app (once or twice) and see that it is inserting again at the current time. Because of this however, I have to go back and backfill everything that wasn't inserted. I'm using the Python psycopg2 library, creating around 6 connections that insert around 5 rows each to the database. I don't understand what is causing this dropping out.

Comment: Depending on how often you communicate with the database some connections might **time out**. Check your application **logs**!

Comment: I unfortunately don't have application logs enabled just yet due to some internal reasons, but I did take a look at the logs for my database and the most that I'm seeing is "could not receive data from client: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host." From the client side, I can still see IO of data through my application so I'm also assuming it has something to do with the database stopping communication with my client. I also looked for any idle connections within Pgsql and found nothing hogging up space, so I'm unsure what I should change in my app?

Comment: The logs are probably the best option here but posting some relevant bits of your code (mainly database communication) might help.